# Tutorial about Writing a JNDI Service Provider

Tags: java, service, jndi, provider

Is there any tutorial about Writing a JNDI Service Provider and accessing the objects and methods from another project to it step by step. There are some information on [Building a service provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/provider/TOC.html) but it is not easy to implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I solved my problem with annotations and global usage of InitialContext class.
Stateless annotation and ejb-jar xml files and accessing the global jndi addresses the keys for usage.

Access Code:

```
this.jndiAddress="ejb/service/IMyInterface";
Context context = new InitialContext();
IMyInterface object = (IMyInterface) context.lookup(this.jndiAddress);
object.doSomething();
```

Service Code;

IMyInterface.java:

```
public interface IMyInterface {

    void doSomething();

}
```

MyClass.java:

```
@Remote(IMyInterface.class)
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/service/IMyInterface")
public class MyClass implements IMyInterface {

    @EJB
    private IMyUserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        User user = userDao.get(1);
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }

}
```

ejb-jar.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Service</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>MyClass</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>package.MyClass</ejb-class>
        </session>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>UserDao</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>package.dao.UserDao</ejb-class>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed the JNDI Tutorial online to help me with what I needed. It is a bit old looking (and written for JDK 1.4.2) but still applicable. [Sun/Oracle JNDI Tutorial.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I read this tutorial but it is not clear in this tutorial what I need. I want to create two project. first one has servlets and behaves as a client and second connects to DB and serves data to client. So The first takes objects from second with JNDI. But my question is "how this configuration is prepared", is there this question's answer in this tutorial? Maybe I have to declare a third project as interface between this two project. Have you any other advice or do I have to read this tutorial more detailed?

Comment: From reading this tutorial you may notice that many different types of objects can be accessed through JNDI. The next challenge to encounter (if you haven't yet) is that some objects can be accessed directly and others can be accessed by reference (depending if you are in container or not). So that is one question. Is your client running in one container and your DB access in anohther? I'm assuming not. Next if you are using DB access why not just use either Entities or Session Beans? These you can access via JNDI and are easy to register with your container. That would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if anyone wants to have a custom JNDI resource in Tomcat check out their [JNDI tutorial](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories).